# Test if string contains only characters

Tags: javascript, regex

The goal is to compose a regex using the .test() or .match() to check if a string contains all numbers.

For example:

1. str "10001" should return true
2. str "1ab001" should return false

So far my regex looks like this:

```
str.match("^[0-9]*$")
```

I'm getting null returned

I am also looking for ways to do this using the .test() method which will return true or false.

Any help with working with regex is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `"10001".match("^[0-9]*$")` => `["10001", index: 0, input: "10001", groups: undefined]`. However, you want `/^\d*$/.test("10001")`

Comment: `"10001".match("^[0-9]*$")` does not return `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp is correct. Using regexp literal you will be able to use test:

```
/^[0-9]*$/.test('10001')
-> true

/^[0-9]*$/.test('10ab001')
-> false
```